# Reduce size of title in MKPinAnnotation

Tags: objective-c, ios, annotations

I have a mapview, with a title and a subtitle for my annotations which are NSString* and I'd like to know if there's any way to change the font size.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On a String Object there is no way to edit font, you should try to use a UILabel. Look at this code:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50)];
label.text = yourString; //You can also use @"string" instead of an NSString
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Oblique" size:(12.0)]; //Font ;)
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

As you can see there is a property to set the font, fot a list of font look that site: http://iosfonts.com/

Comment: Thanks but, Yep, i know that, but when i've my label, how do i add it to my annotation ?

Comment: I think that you have a view, right? You can simply use [yourView addSubview:label];

Comment: Take also a look at CGRectMake of the label

Comment: The thing is that a i have multiples annotations. I tried what you said, and it doesnt work with me... the view of my label is not added to the annotation :/

Comment: How the user type the annotatIon?

Comment: You can create a new class (like this http://pastie.org/2516127) and then [map addAnnotation:[[[GoogleHQAnnotation alloc] init] autorelease]];